# VB.Net Regular expression

Tags: vb.net, regex

I want to have a string in the following format

"FAG001 FAG002 FAG003"

and want to split it into

"FAG001"
"FAG002"
"FAG003"

using a regular expression.  Unfortunately my knowledge of regular expression synatax is limited to say teh least.  I have tried things like

```
Dim result = Regex.Split(npcCodes, "([A-Z]3[0-9]3)").ToList
```

without luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of regex here, you could use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
Dim result As String() = npcCodes.Split(new Char[]{" "})
```

But if you really want to use regex :

```
Dim result = Regex.Split(npcCodes, " ").ToList()
```

Comment: Your regular expression split gives the result `"", "FAG001", " ", "FAG002", " ", "FAG003", ""`, i.e. you are really getting what's between the values, and the values are also included as you catch what you split on...

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a regex because the format I describe above may not be the only format the string is received in

Answer (score 2):

As [madgnome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12248/madgnome) has pointed out you don't need regular expressions here if the string is always separated with spaces.

However for your information the error you made was that you need curly braces for numeric [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
[A-Z]{3}
```

And instead of Regex.Split you can uses [**`Regex.Matches`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression to use in the `Split` method would be really simple:

```
Dim result = Regex.Split(npcCodes, " ").ToList
```

As the expression only matches a single character, you can just as well use the regular `Split` method in the `String` class:

```
Dim result = npcCodes.Split(" "C).ToList
```